# Show multiple row results in SQL Server 2005 as a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I need a query in SQL Server 2005 to combine results from multiple rows into a single row

The data I have relates to clothing sizes like this:

```
#   Item No.    Garment SKU In Stock    
1   CUR211NA-L  CUR211NA    0.00    
2   CUR211NA-LB CUR211NA    10.00   
3   CUR211NA-M  CUR211NA    0.00    
4   CUR211NA-MB CUR211NA    3.00    
5   CUR211NA-S  CUR211NA    0.00    
6   CUR211NA-SB CUR211NA    -9.00   
7   CUR211NA-XL CUR211NA    0.00    
8   CUR211NA-XXL    CUR211NA    0.00    
9   CUR211NA-YTH    CUR211NA    7.00
```

I need to show a single SKU code row with the sizes in columns like this:

```
    SB  MB  LB  YTH S   M   L   XL  XXL
CUR211NA    -9  3   10  7   0   0   0   0   0
```

What I have so far which is showing the quantities correctly but placing every item on a seperate row

```
SELECT distinct T0.[U_GarmentSKU], T0.[U_Garment_Title],

(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('47900')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) 'SB',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('39600')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'MB',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('38500')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'LB',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('50100')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'YTH',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('47700')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'S',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('39400')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'M',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('38300')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'L',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('49200','48700')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'XL',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('49700','49300')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'XXL',
(select  T0.[OnHand]  from oitm t1 where  T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('49800')  and t0.itemcode=t1.itemcode) as 'XXXL'

FROM OITM T0 WHERE T0.[U_GarmentSKU] like 'SUR%' and  T0.[U_StkStat] = 'G'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a subquery.  Either use `pivot` (well, not in SQL Server 2005) or conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT T0.[U_GarmentSKU], T0.[U_Garment_Title],
       SUM(CASE WHEN T0.[U_GarmentSize] IN ('47900') THEN T0.[OnHand] ELSE 0
           END) as SB,
       . . .
FROM OITM T0
WHERE T0.[U_GarmentSKU] like 'SUR%' and  T0.[U_StkStat] = 'G'
GROUP BY T0.[U_GarmentSKU], T0.[U_Garment_Title];
```

Answer (score 0):

The same conditional aggregation as Gordon Linoff's answer, just expanded out for all of the columns in the question:

```
select 
    t.[U_GarmentSKU]
  , t.[U_Garment_Title]
  , [SB]   = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('47900')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [MB]   = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('39600')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [LB]   = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('38500')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [YTH]  = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('50100')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [S]    = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('47700')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [M]    = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('39400')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [L]    = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('38300')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [XL]   = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('49200','48700') then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [XXL]  = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('49700','49300') then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
  , [XXXL] = sum(case when t.[U_GarmentSize] in ('49800')         then t.[OnHand] else 0 end)
from oitm t
where t.[U_GarmentSKU] like 'SUR%' 
  and t.[U_StkStat] = 'G'
group by t.[U_GarmentSKU], t.[U_Garment_Title]
```

Comment: many thanks you guys!   both great answers and both did exactly what I needed.